# Probability of a sample mean from a continuous distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Simple question, which I'm pretty confident my teacher is conveying incorrectly:

If I have a continuous random variable, and take a finite sample from it (say, n=50), what is the probability of any individual number being the mean?

I figure since it's from a continuous random distribution, the probability of any individual mean is 0. He suggests it's nonzero (in particular he says it's 95% which I know is crap but I wanna know if it's 0).

Comment: Indeed, 0. $ $ $ $

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: @Did Thank you. The fact that the population is finite is also completely inconsequential, correct?

Comment: @sperky What population?

Comment: I think your teacher is referring to a confidence interval for the mean. There is a 95% chance that the 95% Confidence Interval will contain the true mean *before you collect an actual sample*.